# d3 y-scale bar height difference

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale, rect

I'm drawing a chart but have trouble how to handle my y scale and that my rectangles are drawn "upon" each over. (I draw with the bars from y-axis)

I calculate how high each bar needs to be and if a bar is higher than my default height the y does not manage to handle this. I'm not shure how to handle this. I draw my rect:

```
forms.append("rect")
.attr("class", "rectStyle")
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.Name); })
.attr("x", function(d){ return x(new Date(d.startDate));}) 
.attr("height",function(d) { return d.barHeight;})
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.RowGroup);})
.attr("width", function(d){ d.w = (x(new Date(d.endDate))-x(new Date(d.startDate)));
    return d.w; });
y  = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([1,noRows])
.range([0,height -margin.top-margin.bottom-padding*noRows]);
```

Grateful for how I should solve this problem

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/)?

Comment: Thank you Lars
I've seen that one. The height in that tutorial is what i call i width in the code above. I'm doing a combination of a gantt and treemap. I need to keep track of my "RowGroup" since I've got other stuff connected to that axis so. I might not understand the tutorial correct. It's my bars width that might differ in size I was not clear enough when I explained.
I've got everything else working except of when the bars Width is different from the default

Comment: Ah ok, it wasn't clear to me that you're doing something different from a bar chart. When a bar is wider, do you want to shrink the other bars or reposition this particular one or what do you want to do?

Comment: Just adjust that specific bar. I've already calculated each bar individually to be able that there is room for the dots that I have drawn inside the bar. Right now It feels like I can't think any more :-)

Comment: So you just want to check whether the computed width exceeds a certain maximum and if so, cut it off there?

Comment: No. 
For example if i have a bar that would start on 100 for the y-value and a bar width on 50(this one belongs to RowGroup 1). The next one should have a start value to be 150(Belongs to RowGroup2). Even if the second bar belongs to RowGroup 2 that normally should start on 125. 

Hope it's explains my problem in a better way

Comment: So the width of a particular bar may affect the position of another bar?

Comment: Yes, I know loop through and calculate each y-value but wonder if there is a smarter way to do it

Comment: It sounds like this is the way to go.